# C MPI - Best way to automate multimple runs and keep logs and info. + Predifing global variables

Tags: c, io, mpi

I want to test a couple of algorithms that i wrote and instead of doing it by repeating the procedure, changing variables and write down the outputs, i want to implement an automation for this procedure. I would like this to be like a script type where i can declare the number of processors, some variables and definitely have a formated output with all the conclusions of the multiple runs. The format of the output could be a text format, but it wouldn't bother me if i could use later that file for creating a 2 dimensional graph etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a shell script to spawn all the combinations you want to test. Have your code produce output in such a way that you can determine which parameters it used. I send the output to a file whose name lists all the parameters.

edit:

in your program:

```
// ensure argc >= 4

int   argA = atoi(argv[1]);
float argB = atof(argv[2]);

char* output_filename = argv[3];
```

in your script:

```
for A in 1 2 3
do
    for B in 0.1 0.2 0.3
    do
         mpirun a.out $A $B results_of_run_${A}_${B}.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: That's the idea, but i have difficulties implementing it. For example i have 3 global variables x,y,z that i want to change throughout the procedure. First the program has to be compiled and then run for a number of processes. Lastly is the file. What format should it be and how i could make it not erase every previous entries when writing in the file (in my experience when you call multiple times a program that writes into a file, it keeps re-writing the data all over the file.

Comment: Add command-line support for setting those global variables to your program (i.e. use `argv`). Have the output filename reflect your parameters so that you don't keep overwriting the same output file. Either generate a filename internally (least favorite), use another switch so the script specifies the output filename, or output to `stdout` and use OS to send to appropriate file (pipe if shared memory or PBS outfile setting if not).

Comment: You could also use have your program interrogate environment variables to set your parameters, or even use a config file, but IMHO the command-line route is the easiest and cleanest. In case you're wondering, there is no way to set a program's globals from outside that program.

Comment: First things first.Which is it? Can or can't i pass integer arguments from the command line while i run a program (or in this case an automate script)? Argv and Argc are for passing string arguments not integer. Plus, this will  be executed into a parallel cluster using MPI (mpicc & mpiexec) - MPICH to be clear.

Comment: Secondly, what does the output file have anything to do with the script? The output file is made and write by the actual program. I must say my knowledge to this is pretty minimal, but care to elaborate on the output piping method. I would follow the `fprint` way to write on text, but as i said it keeps overwriting over the file with each execution. And this problem is worse in parallel where every processor keeps overwriting the file while into a single execution. _Also_ i was thinking that the script could be a bash script.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for the extra help with the details. One question though, what were you trying to do with `char* output_filename = argv[3];` ? I will use `printf()` for the output and then pipe it to a text file with `./script.sh > file.txt` cause i don't really need multiple files of the results. Thanks again

Comment: And an other one. Is there a way to use the for loop in a script like in **C** `for i=0 to 10` _or_ use a variable from the script (like $A and $B as you mentioned) like this : `for B in 0.1*$A 0.2*$A 0.3*$A` I try it and i see that the string gets passed correctly (showing the value of A instead of $A) but when i try to convert it to integer it keeps only the first value (0.1 0.2 0.3).

Comment: You said you used fprintf to print to a file. If you're redirecting stdout then sure you don't have to pass anything to the file. But yes you do need multiple files of results, otherwise how are you going to tell what result comes from what parameters?

Comment: `fprintf` is a pain with MPI. I can use `echo` for printing from inside the script, to divide equally each result. As for showing the parameters is still doable, either from inside the program or from the script. If i wanted something more automated and the output would be automatically inserted into a server or something, then your solution would be optimal.